# In nodeJS how to use database environment when NODE_ENV calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, database

hi am new to nodejs environment.

am using nodeJs + compoundjs.

am having three database environment development. production and test. my question in when i  run the NODE_ENV=production node . command, all url's,port number and other things should get from   production.js. when i shift the node environment by giving command NODE_ENV=development node . all things need to run should get from development.js.

any notes for this also helpful for me.

if anybody has any idea please share with me.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the Environment and then you can configure your app like:

(This is a mongoose db and express, but you can find similar configurations.)

Simply set up three environment configurations

```
app.configure('development', function () {
  mongoose.connect(devConfig.db.path, function onMongooseError(err) {
  });
});

app.configure('production', function () {
  mongoose.connect(proConfig.db.path, function onMongooseError(err) {
  });
});
```

a configuration example (config.js) :

```
var config = {};

// Database (MongoDB) configurations
config.db = {
path : 'mongodb://localhost/sampleDatabase'
};

module.exports = config;
```

I require this file in my `app.js` by `var config = require('config')`

You could do the Environment detection in the config file as well.

Comment: what is that devConfig.db.path and proConfig.db.path in your code.

Comment: it is a simple .json file which you can have on your harddisk or as an object. I have a module containting the configuration, i will attache an example to the answer

Comment: ya right now am doing similarly getting url or path form config.js. here my problem is when i switch from various environment all details are from same config file i want to get details from environment development.js test.js like vise.. did u got what am trying to ask?

Comment: i think you can try setting environment variables and read them in your config file or you create a seperate file for each configuration, the example file in 3 variations would do it

Comment: note that i am loading different config files for each environment